# Finding the correct Python framework with cmake

Tags: python, frameworks, macos, cmake, macports

I am using the macports version of python on a Snow Leopard computer, and using cmake to build a cross-platform extension to it. I search for the python interpreter and libraries on the system using the following commands in CMakeLists.txt

```
include(FindPythonInterp)
include(FindPythonLibs  )
```

However, while cmake identified the correct interpreter in `/opt/local/bin`, it tries to link against the wrong framework - namely the system Python framework.

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /opt/local/bin/python2.6
-- Found PythonLibs: -framework Python
```

And this causes the following runtime error

```
Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)
```

As soon as I replace `-framework Python` with `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python` things seem to work as expected.

How can I make cmake link against the correct Python framework found in

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python
```

rather than the system one in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the following in `~/.bash_profile`

```
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks
```

fixes the problem at least temporarily. Apparently, this inconsistency between the python interpreter and the python framework used by cmake is a bug that should be hopefully fixed in the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I am not intimately familiar with CMake, but with the Apple version of gcc/ld, you can pass the `-F` flag to specify a new framework search path. For example, `-F/opt/local/Library/Frameworks` will search in MacPorts' frameworks directory. If you can specify such a flag using CMake, it may solve your problem.